# Marker at the end of arrow line in QGIS 3 with offset

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, visualisation

I have a line layer for arrows in QGIS 3, and I'd like to display a marker at the end of each arrow. I tried to add a marker line on top of my arrow with a marker placed only on the last vertex, but it overlaps with the end arrow.

I suppose the ideal way would be somehow to define that I want to display my arrow line at eg 0.8 length, but not sure how to do that. A simple line visualization has a trim options, but there is nothing like that for an arrow line, and I cannot make a simple line curved.

This is how it looks now.

[image]

I would like to avoid the visible overlap.

Comment: Don't understand how your result should look like. Please post a screenshot showing what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is how it looks like currently: [link](https://imgur.com/a/LR5Msu1)
I'd like to avoid the overlap of a marker on the last vertex and the arrow.

Comment: You should add this image to your initial question by clicking edit... So the marker (dot) should be under the arrow, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the symbol layer containing the point symbol below the line representing the arrow:

[image]

To avoid overlap at all and to make the arrow-line shorter, you can set the symbol layer type to geometry generator and use this expression, where `0.98` represents an end-point at 98% of the total line's length from the start point:

```
line_substring (
    $geometry, 
    0, 
    $length*0.98)
```

This, however, results in the arrow not pointing to the real end point any more as the end-point of the initial line in fact is shifted:

*initial line dotted in black, arrow in blue*
[image]

To overcome this, change the expression for geometry generator to:

```
line_substring (
    smooth($geometry, 1),
    0,
    $length*0.95)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the answer. I tried to set it up exactly as you described, but my arrow is far from the point. Any idea what am I doing wrong?
[link](https://imgur.com/a/NKGn7i0)

I also tried to set it up to 1, the arrow moves a little bit closer, but not much.
`$lenght*1`

Setting it up to 1.25 looks alright, but is it a right approach? I though value 1 is the full length of the line.

Comment: Try `lenght($geometry)` instead. Better? What CRS is your layer in?

Comment: Can you share project+sample data for testing

Comment: I'm using WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator EPSG:3857. I tried to create a new project, same layer and CRS, and it works as it should. No idea, but it's on my side. Thanks for the help!